# Install package using npm error

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm following npm documentation here https://docs.npmjs.com/all to learn properly how to use it, I manages to download correcly node and npm, version checked properly then i change npm's default directory to another directory, now is like this:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ macetti$ npm config get prefix
/Users/macetti/npm-global
```

The problem is that then when i try to install with this command

```
npm install lodash
```

appear this

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "lodash"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/macetti/npm-debug.log
```

Here my npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install', 'lodash' ]
2 info using npm@2.10.1
3 info using node@v0.12.4
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /Users/macetti/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose install initial load of /Users/macetti/package.json
6 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from /Users/macetti/package.json
7 silly cache add args [ 'lodash', null ]
8 verbose cache add spec lodash
9 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'lodash',
9 silly cache add   scope: null,
9 silly cache add   name: 'lodash',
9 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
9 silly cache add   spec: '*',
9 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
10 silly addNamed lodash@*
11 verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for lodash
12 silly addNameRange { name: 'lodash', range: '*', hasData: false }
13 silly mapToRegistry name lodash
14 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
15 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
16 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
17 verbose addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash not in flight; fetching
18 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
19 verbose request no auth needed
20 info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:54:46
21 verbose request id f688faead59da217
22 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
23 verbose stack Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
23 verbose stack     at Error (native)
23 verbose stack     at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:108:19)
23 verbose stack     at Object.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:852:21)
23 verbose stack     at Agent.createConnection (https.js:82:14)
23 verbose stack     at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:194:16)
23 verbose stack     at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:166:23)
23 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
23 verbose stack     at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
23 verbose stack     at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
23 verbose stack     at Request.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:963:30)
24 verbose cwd /Users/macetti
25 error Darwin 14.4.0
26 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "lodash"
27 error node v0.12.4
28 error npm  v2.10.1
29 error error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
30 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
30 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
31 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I was looking for solve problem, I tryied several solution but nothing solved the issue.

Someone can help me please?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8734, similar issues occur are related to the installation package, as opposed to the NPN installation.  I would log a issue on the vendor (lodash) for resolution on the error.

Ref (npm/issues/8734):

```
./bin/www  must exists and contains valid  index.js  file.
You can change folder value for  start  property.

I think it's not a NPM issue, please close this issue.
Go on StackOverflow or Google something like  express npm start node ./bin/www 

I hope I have helped you.
```

AND

```
After install do  npm install -g npm@2.12.1 .

Check your version with  npm -v .

If the problem persist, your issue concern  express  or your package configuration not npm.
```

Comment: I triyng to follow what you write, on /usr/local/bin there was not folder www so I create it and inside I put index.js. This theoretically should be create during the installation isn't it?

Sorry but what content should a put on index.js ?

I don't know if if npm issue or not, but I just follow what explained on npm documentation and know I cannot install any package, I try with different one but result are the same.

Can you maybe help me to solve this please?

Comment: Do you think should be better set permission folder as default as was at the beginning? now is /Users/macetti/npm-global
Maybe could be the problem? I follow step by step to change it and there was no error but before change permission folder I manage to install correcly a package

Comment: Did you write the package yourself or was it written by a third party?

Comment: yes I change title, is it wrong? as when I wrote I thought that problem was npm and you said that is package I thought to change title so someone can help me. If you think is wrong I can delete it and create a new issue but I don't understand the sense of close this issue and reopen with a new title, anyway I'm new and I accept if you tell me that will be better.

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide any more.  Not had this issue before, but though I could help.